# Knockout bindings from a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout and trying to create my first script which update based on a JSO script which constantly change. The problem is i keep seem to get an unexpected error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.3.0.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

callService();

var Match = function(){
 var self = this;
 self.matches = ko.observableArray();

 self.ajax = function (uri, method, data) {
    var request = {
        url: uri,
        type: method,
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
        }
    };
    return $.ajax(request);
}


function callService(){
    self.ajax(url + "matchticker.json" + requestData, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.matches.removeAll();
        for(int i = 0; i < data.Result.length; i++){
            self.matches.push(..data..);
        }
    }
}


}

ko.applyBindings(new Match());


</script>

</head>

<body>
<ul class="list-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-bind='foreach: matches'>
  <li data-bind="html: match_id"></li>
</ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Why are you pushing ..data.. and not data.Result[i]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many syntax errors here. Next time try linting your code first.
See if it works:

```
var Match = function(){

    var self = this;
    self.matches = ko.observableArray();

    self.ajax = function (uri, method, data) {
        var request = {
            url: uri,
            type: method,
            contentType: "application/json",
            accepts: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                console.log("ajax error " + jqXHR.status);
            }
        };
        return $.ajax(request);
    };


    function callService(){
        self.ajax(url + "matchticker.json" + requestData, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.matches.removeAll();
            for(var i = 0; i < data.Result.length; i++){
                self.matches.push(data.Result[i]);
            }
        });
    }

    callService();

};

ko.applyBindings(new Match());
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: callService is not defined

Comment: You are calling a function (callService) that is out of scope.

Comment: So how could i for instance call the callService every 5 seconds?

Comment: You need to call function callService within it's scope. I edited my answer above.

Comment: You would need to add a setInterval() for that.

Comment: Thank you for your time i appreciate it. url and requestData is not defined. Do i need to define this if yes? with what?

Comment: You are making an AJAX request, therefore you need to know the URL of the API you will be making the calls to.

Comment: So url would be equal to the root for instance my server id? and what would requestData be?

Comment: Hi Peter, I don't have these answers, you do :) You can always hire me though ;)

Comment: I definitely could, but student payments and hiring people does not always work well together for the economy ;) Thank you for you're time.